# How do I correct the GeoTransform of a GRIB dataset if I scale/crop the data?

Tags: python, gdal, grib-2

I have modified the GRIB2 data to be cropped and a different size. I'd like to create a new GRIB2 file which contains this modified dataset. How do I calculate the new GeoTransform and create it using gdal? Do I need to modify the Projection too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to modify the projection, only the GeoTransform.

In order to do this modification, it's necessary to know the new top-left corner of the data, and the new pixel spacing relative to the old one.

First, save the current GeoTransform:

```
current_gt=grib2_inst.GetGeoTransform()
```

Work out the new pixel spacing. If you've interpolated your data such that it's now 3x wider and taller, then it's necessary to divide element [1] in the geotransform by 3. Essentially, the pixels are 1/3 of the distance apart.

```
pix_spacing = current_gt[1]/3
```

Calculate the new top-left corner. If you cropped at point 600 (x) and 50(y), then use those like so:

```
    ulx=current_gt[0] + 600*current_gt[1] + 50*current_gt[2]
    uly=current_gt[3] + 600*current_gt[4] + 50*current_gt[5]
```

Finally, construct the new transform:

```
    new_gt = (ulx,pix_spacing,current_gt[2],
              uly,current_gt[4],-pix_spacing)
```

And apply it to your new instance:

```
tiff_image.SetGeoTransform(new_gt)
```